# Error in using weighted_mean with summarise_at in R (dplyr package)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am getting the following error message when trying to use `weighted_mean` as the aggregation function for `summarise_at` in R (`dplyr` package):

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
>         Evaluation error: 'x' and 'w' must have the same length.

Here is my code:

```
a = data.frame(snapshot_date = c("1-Jan-2016", "1-Jan-2016", "1-Feb-2016", "1-Feb-2016"),
           rate = c(0.75, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1),
           newrate = c(0.9, 0.4, 0.6, 0.3),
           balance = c(1000,2000,3000,4000))
b = a %>%
  group_by(snapshot_date)

summarise_at(.tbl = b,
            .vars = c("rate", "newrate"),
           .funs = weighted.mean, 
           w = b$balance, na.rm = FALSE)
```

When I remove the weight argument, I no longer get an error message and I get correct (unweighted) results, as follows:

```
summarise_at(.tbl = b,
         .vars = c("rate", "newrate"),
         .funs = weighted.mean, 
         na.rm = FALSE)
```

yields:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  snapshot_date  rate newrate
  <fct>         <dbl>   <dbl> 
1 1-Feb-2016    0.300   0.450
2 1-Jan-2016    0.475   0.650
>
```

What I am doing wrong when trying to use the weights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where it is going wrong exactly unfortunately, but this way it would work

```
b = a %>%
  group_by(snapshot_date) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(rate, newrate), funs(weighted.mean(., balance)))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  snapshot_date  rate newrate
  <fct>         <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1-Feb-2016    0.271   0.429
2 1-Jan-2016    0.383   0.567
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  It looks like the "funs" helper function is required, in order to allow "balance" to be used properly as the weighting factor, given that it is part of the tibble itself.

Comment: @StevenBarkin If this post solves your question, please consider to accept it as the answer. See this post (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to learn how to do it.